# Why does the integral of cot x have absolute value?

Tags: calculus, integration

There's a proof of that integral on this website:
http://math2.org/math/integrals/more/cot.htm

I just don't understand why we need the absolute value.

Comment: What's the natural log of $-1$? Notice that $\sin(x)=-1$ at infintely many points.

Comment: The logarithm of negative numbers are imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot take the logarithm of a negative number.

Notice that $\dfrac{d}{dw} \log w = \dfrac1w$ (where $w$ is positive) and $\dfrac{d}{dw}\log(-w)$ (where $w$ is negative, so $-w$ is positive) is also $\dfrac1w$.

So $\dfrac{d}{dx}\log\sin x = \cot x$ for values of $x$ for which $\sin x$ is positive.

And $\dfrac{d}{dx}\log(-\sin x)=\cot x$ for value of $x$ for which $\sin x$ is negative, so that $-\sin x$ is positive.

Answer (score 3):

You want an answer that also works on an interval where $\sin x$ is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the integral of $\cot(x)$ for $x\in[0,\pi]$ to be $\log(\sin(x))+C$. Then note that since $\cot(x)$ is an odd function, its integral will be an even function. Thus, the integral for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ will be $\log(\sin(|x|))+C$. By the periodicity, we get that the integral is $\log(|\sin(x)|)+C$.

Comment: Isn't it $sin x$ and not $csc x$? Thanks! I love the use of odd and even functions.

Comment: @Raindrop: you are right. Although $\log(\csc(x))$ is positive, $\log(\sin(x))$ is increasing.

Comment: I don't get it. The formal answers (the answer key of my textbook and the website link in my question) say the answer is **ln** sin x. The answers on this website say the answer is **log** sin x. How could ln and log be used interchangeabley?
Is it somehow assumed that I know you are referring to $log_{e}$ and not just $log_{10}$? I understand that the natural log refers to ln a.k.a. $log_{e}$.

Comment: @Raindrop: if I'm talking to a mathematician, I assume all $\log$ and $\ln$ are natural logs, unless otherwise specified. When I was in grad school, engineers would use $\log$ for common and $\ln$ for natural. I apologize for any confusion. In my posts, I use $\log$ and mean natural log.